# Inverse of Supplier<T> in Guava

Tags: java, functional-programming, guava

I'm looking for the inverse of `Supplier<T>` in Guava.  I hoped it would be called `Consumer` – nope – or `Sink` – exists, but is for primitive values.

Is it hidden somewhere and I'm missing it?

I'd like to see it for the same kinds of reasons that `Supplier` is useful.  Admittedly, uses are less common, but many of the static methods of `Suppliers`, for example, would apply in an analogous way, and it would be useful to express in one line things like "send this supplier every value in this iterable".

In the meantime, `Predicate` and `Function<T,Void>` are ugly workarounds.

Comment: Probably not helpful but there is a Consumer<T> in... Java 8.

Comment: You might actually be looking for a binary function, which could then be applied to reduce/fold operation. Many basic statistical functions could be implemented that way (eg. avg, stddev, sum, min, max). This has been proposed on the Guava issues list, but was regarded as 'too functional'.

Comment: In this case I'm not - I want a unary function returning void, that accepts T.

For example, the typical loop:

`for (T elem : iterable) {
   sink.consume(elem);
}`

would be replaced by something like `Iterables.apply(iterable, sink)` (or perhaps `Consumables.consume`, etc).

Comment: _In the meantime, Predicate and Function<T,Void> are ugly workarounds._ - for-each loop is elegant solution then (until Java 8).

Comment: +1 @Xaerxess.  The primary reason Guava doesn't have this is that we don't have compelling use cases: as of Java 7, as far as we can tell, it's generally cleaner to write this sort of code directly, without using an object to encapuslate the callback.

Comment: `RxJava2` has `io.reactivex.functions.Consumer` which works with Java 7 and in particular earlier Android versions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your alternatives are:

- **Java 8** introduces a [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) interface which you can [compose](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html#andThen-java.util.function.Consumer-).
- **[Xtend](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend)**'s standard library contains [`Procedures`](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/javadoc/2.3/org/eclipse/xtext/xbase/lib/Procedures.html).
- **[Scala](http://scala-lang.org/)** has [`Function*`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function1); if a function's return type is [`Unit`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Unit), it is considered a side effect.

In all of these languages, you can use functional interfaces conveniently, so you could also use e.g. [Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org/)'s [`Effect`](http://functionaljava.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/3.0/javadoc/fj/Effect.html).

**Otherwise**, you better rely on existing language constructs for performing side effects, e.g. the built-in `for` loop. Java < 8 inflicts tremendous syntactic overhead when using lambdas. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525951/anything-in-guava-similar-to-functional-javas-effect) and [this discussion](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Function` and set the second Argument to [java.lang.Void](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) this `Function` can only return `null`.

Answer (score -1):

You have already found the answer. If you just want to visit, you can use filter with a predicate that always returns true; if you are super defensive you can use any predicate and use an or function with an alwaysTrue in the filter itself; just add the `or` at the end to avoid shortcircuiting.

The problem is that even though I agree that conceptually Predicate and Consumer are different since a Predicate should be as stateless as possible and not have side effects while a consumer is only about the side effects, in practice the only syntactic difference is that one returns a boolean (that can be ignored) and the other void. If Guava had a Consumer, it would need to either duplicate several of the methods that take a Predicate to also take a Consumer or have Consumer inherit from Predicate.

Comment: The problem is that the classes that would implement this are named, general purpose classes and to have them implement Predicate-always-returns-true would be confusing. You could equivalently argue that Supplier<T> is useless - you might as well use Function<Void,T>, ignoring the input.

Comment: Note that Iterables.filter() is lazy, so the "Predicate" consumer won't be called until you actually iterate on the resulting Iterable, which is quite ugly and could lead to bugs... You'd need to write something like `Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.filter(iterable, predicateThatIsActuallyAConsumer));`. I'd rather use a for loop, and a project-specific `Consumer` class.

Comment: -1 because this does not contribute to the question. A predicate has different behavior and a different type. It would misuse the type system and lead to misunderstanding. It's a hack.